# AdSense Ads giving error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: ads, adsense, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to display AdSense ads on my website, but for some reason they do not load. I've added the ads a couple of days ago as I've heard it can take a while for them to be displayed, but there is no change up til now.

In "Inspect", I can see the following error showing up when the site is supposed to load the ads.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

I am runnning this AdSense account from 5 years, same adcodes working in other websites. What might the issue be and how can this be resolved?

Comment: https://www.problogbooster.com/2015/01/adsense-403-forbidden-error-html-google-adsense-not-showing-ad-code-403-fix-solved-troubleshoot.html

Comment: 1) Check your Adsense code: It is already checked.
2) Add your website to Adsense account: It is already checked.
3) Check with your hosting service: We have checked server settings from our end and it is not being blocked from our end (DigitalOcean Reply).
4) Cloudflare: Not applicable because the site is not using Cloudflare

Comment: @ThulasiRam did you ever get this issue fixed?

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: This is probably a long shot, but have you checked if the website is loading with or without "www"? Note that this makes a difference when adding the domain to your adsens account.

Comment: The problem happens to me . so i thing wa have to waiting adsens accept the site before add the codes

Answer (score 2):

In my case Google needed to review my site again. Log into Adsense and you can request a review.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I contacted my hosting providers who advised that I should turn off Mod Security which worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the domain you run on the google asSense code matches the domain you registered at google adSense.

For exmaple if you will run it on dev. mode locally it will produce also the same error because it doesn't matches the domain.

Answer (score -1):

Hey did you added new site and it was reviewed and approved too ?

You cant directly put your adcodes in any site. Until the site is approved by AdSense.

Note: When you add a site in AdSense account. Then it need to get reviewed and approved.

If site is approved then wait for a day or saw to get Ads live.